# How to integrate django shop with django cms?

Tags: python, django, content-management-system, e-commerce, integration

I want to use Django Shop with the Django CMS.

It should be possible to add the Django Shop app to a page (for example: products).
It also should use category pages for product listing (`products/print/books/`).
It should display a detail template on a product page (`products/print/books/hardcover`).

I didn't find it easy to integrate Django Shop with Django CMS as advertised on the official Django website. Is it possible to overwrite/extend or add files to the Django Shop App? I don't want to hack the code of the app.

Comment: did you manage to do this?  I'm considering using Django-CMS and either Django-Shop or Django-Oscar

Comment: @toasteez i discontinued this django project.

Comment: do you think Django CMS could be integrated with any python ecommerce?

Comment: @toasteez Sorry, I don't know.

Answer (score 1):

Django-shop can be integrated with django-cms. There are two common cases in general: from scratch and add django-shop to an existing app based on django-cms. The first case is pretty simple: you can use django-shop cookiecutter template 
https://github.com/awesto/cookiecutter-django-shop 
and get already working integration. All you need is to customize this skeleton.

The second case is not so obvious. You need to install django-shop as a dependency:
`pip install django-shop`. Then you will probably want to override at least Commodity model. You can do it according to the deferred model pattern: 
https://django-shop.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/deferred-models.html 
In case of already existing app you can have the problems with the User model if it's overridden in the main app. To solve it, I'd recommend you this fork 
https://github.com/Dimitrionian/django-shop 
which uses overridden User model from the main app.